# call specs2 def with parameter

Tags: scala, specs2, string-interpolation

I have my spec2 test setup as follows

```
def is =
    sequential ^
      s2"""
      Action
        should return false for param false   $test(false)
                                                                             """
```

Def of test is as follows

```
def test(param: Boolean): Boolean
```

However I get compile time error saying missing argument for method test in my definition for is. How can I get this right?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing some curlies `${test(false)}`

Comment: @SaschaKolberg thanks that solved it :)